# minimize smallest eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume $P_A,P_B$ are probability transition matrices (each element is nonnegative and row sum is 1) and $v$ is probability row vector (each element is nonnegative and sum of elements is 1). How to solve the following optimization:
$$\min_v \lambda_{\min}\left(P_A (\operatorname{diag}(vP_A))^{-1}P_A^T- P_B (\operatorname{diag}(vP_B))^{-1}P_B^T\right)$$
where $\operatorname{diag}(x)$ is diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to the corresponding entries in row vector $x$.